New Beta Theme Launched
Your site looks a bit different today. Yes, we are getting rid of the 'Sketchy' look and replacing it with a more-polished and finished design for sites in beta.
You can read more about the redesign of our Beta theme on our blog entry.
Please note: This will not affect your "graduation" status in any way. When your site is due for graduation, it will get its final(real) site design and branding.
If you're still seeing the old favicon, please do a hard browser refresh. (Although sometimes it may take Chrome a while to load the new image).
If you see any CSS or styling issues, please report it in this post I created on Meta Stack Overflow. It will be easier for me to track all the bug reports there.

Cheers Jin, very smart, I've been looking forward to this :)

Loving the new favicon too - I was worried we'd lose our brick ;)

It's a clean look, but have to admit that I kind of like the Sketchy motif better - guess I was just used to it. Glad we kept the brick though. :)
